# How to read a cell in excel using a python for loop?

Tags: python, excel

I am making an excel file reading program in python. I want it to read each cell in a particular column. I used a for loop for this.
This is my code:

```
location = "C:\\Users\\user2\\Desktop\\Python\\Other\\blah.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
rownum = 1
for word in (sheet.cell_value(rownum,2)):
    print(word)
    rownum += 1
```

And I get the result:

```
R
E
S
T
A
R
T

I
S
S
U
E

/

R
A
M

P
R
O
B
L
E
M
```

Instead, I want the result to show word by word, not letter by letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
for word in (sheet.cell_value(rownum,2)):
```

Use

```
for word in (sheet.cell_value(rownum,2).split(' ')):
```

If you use `for` on a string, it will iterate over single characters